# Manage G Suite for Client

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

One of my client want me to help them to purchase and manage G Suite account for them. Meaning, the G suite will be paid using my credit card and they will pay to me. So, how can I have the G Suite account that belongs to them and I am able to manage & renew G Suite for them without creating an additional paid email account for me?

Answer (score 1):

you have to become the google suite reseller

I just gave the sample link

```
https://cloud.google.com/partners/become-a-partner
```

according to where you live, contact the country google sales team. hopes this helps